# Deriving optimized strlen in assembler?

Tags: assembly

The following code is able to figure out if a DWORD has one or more of its bytes set to 0.

```
mov eax, value
mov edx, 07EFEFEFFh
add edx, eax
xor eax, 0FFFFFFFFh
xor eax, edx
and eax, 081010100h
```

For example, if we input 34323331h, eax = 0
Yet if we input something where 1 byte is set to 00, such as 34003231h, eax != 0

I know what this code does, but I don't understand how it does it.  How does this mathematically work? Can someone explain the process with bits to me and how this was derived?

It should be relatively simple, but I just can't see it

Comment: to check if a value contains a zero byte or not there are other faster ways: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll count bits starting from 0 from right.

### Short answer:

When you add `11111111` to zero byte (`00000000`), then the overflow bit (8th bit) **does not** differ from `value + 0x7EFEFEFF`'s same overflow bit.

When you add `11111111` to non-zero byte, then the overflow bit (8th bit) **does** differ from `value + 0x7EFEFEFF`'s same overflow bit.

The program just checks those bits.

### Long answer:

This is the mathematical representation of the code (`a` is the value):

```
result = ((a + magic) ^ !a) & !magic
```

where

- `magic` is `0x7EFEFEFF`
- `^` means bitwise xor
- `&` means bitwise and
- `!` means bitwise reversed, aka xor'd with `0xFFFFFFFF`

To understand the role of `0x7EFEFEFF`, look at it's binary represenatation:

```
01111110 11111110 11111110 11111111
```

The `0`'s are magic overflow bits. These are bits number 8, 16, 24 and 31.

Let's look at a few examples.

### Example 1: `eax = 0x00000000`

```
a         = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
a+magic   = 01111110 11111110 11111110 11111111
!a        = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

When we xor `a+magic` with `!a` we get:

```
result    = 10000001 00000001 00000001 00000000
```

Here look at the magic bits. They are all `1`.

Then we simply clear the rest of the bits (which are all `0` here) by `and`ing the result by `10000001 00000001 00000001 00000000` aka `!magic`. As you know, `and`ing by 0 simply assigns 0 to that bit and `and`ing by 1 does nothing to that bit.

Final result:

```
10000001 00000001 00000001 00000000
```

### Example 2: `eax = 0x00000001`

```
a         = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
a+magic   = 01111110 11111110 11111111 00000000
!a        = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

When we xor `a+magic` with `!a` we get:

```
result    = 10000001 00000001 00000000 11111110
```

Look at the magic bits. Bits number 16, 24 and 31 are 1. 8th bit is 0.

- 8th bit represents the first byte. If the first byte is not zero, 8th bit becomes `1` at this point. Otherwise it's `0`.
- 16th bit represents the second byte. Same logic.
- 24th bit represents the third byte.
- 31th bit represents the fourth byte.

Then again we clear non-magic bits by `and`ing the result with `!magic`.

Final result:

```
10000001 00000001 00000000 00000000
```

### Example 3: `eax = 0x34003231`

```
a         = 00110100 00000000 00110010 00110001
a+magic   = 10110010 11111111 00110001 00110000
!a        = 11001011 11111111 11001101 11001110
```

When we xor `a+magic` with `!a` we get:

```
result    = 01111001 00000000 11111100 11111110
```

Only 24th bit is `1`

After clearing non-magic bits the final result is:

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

### Example 4: `eax = 0x34323331`

```
a         = 00110100 00110010 00110011 00110001
a+magic   = 10110011 00110001 00110010 00110000
!a        = 11001011 11001101 11001100 11001110
```

When we xor `a+magic` with `!a` we get:

```
result    = 01111000 11111100 11111110 11111110
```

After clearing non-magic bits the final result is:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (zero)
```

---

I wrote a test case for demonstration:

```
#include <stdint.h> // uint32_t
#include <stdio.h> // printf

//assumes little endian
void printBits(size_t const size, void const * const ptr)
{
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) ptr;
    unsigned char byte;
    int i, j;

    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            byte = b[i] & (1 << j);
            byte >>= j;
            printf("%u", byte);
        }

        printf(" ");
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t a = 0;
    uint32_t d = 0;
    const uint32_t magic = 0x7EFEFEFF;
    const uint32_t magicRev = magic ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;

    const uint32_t numbers[] = {
        0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x34003231,
        0x34323331, 0x01010101
    };


    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[ 0 ]); i++) {
        a = numbers[ i ];
        d = magic;

        printf("a:            ");
        printBits(sizeof(a), &a);
        printf("\n");

        d = a + d;

        printf("a+magic:      ");
        printBits(sizeof(d), &d);
        printf("\n");

        a = a ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;

        printf("!a:           ");
        printBits(sizeof(a), &a);
        printf("\n");

        a = a ^ d;

        printf("result:       ");
        printBits(sizeof(a), &a);
        printf("\n");

        a = a & magicRev;

        printf("              ");
        printBits(sizeof(a), &a);

        if (a == 0) {
            printf(" (zero)\n");
        } else {
            printf(" (at least one)\n");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```