# Understanding the magic number 0x07EFEFEFF used for strlen optimization

Tags: c, assembly, bit-manipulation, strlen

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772107/2286508) regarding the utilization of the magic number 0x07EFEFEFF used for `strlen`'s optimization, and here is what the top answer says:

> Look at the magic bits. Bits number 16, 24 and 31 are 1. 8th bit is 0.
>
> - 8th bit represents the first byte. If the first byte is not zero, 8th bit becomes `1` at this point. Otherwise it's `0`.
> - 16th bit represents the second byte. Same logic.
> - 24th bit represents the third byte.
> - 31th bit represents the fourth byte.

However, if I calculate `result = ((a + magic) ^ ~a) & ~magic` with `a = 0x100`, I find that `result = 0x81010100`, meaning that according to the top answerer, the second byte of `a` equals 0, which is obviously false.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe the result actually tells you which byte is zero. It only tells you if at least one byte is zero or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bits only tell you if a byte is zero if the lower bytes are non-zero -- so it can only tell you the FIRST 0 byte, but not about bytes after the first 0.

- bit8=1 means first byte is zero.  Other bytes, unknown
- bit8=0 means first byte is non-zero
- bit8=0 & bit16=1 means second byte is zero,  higher bytes unknown
- bit8=0 & bit16=0 mans first two bytes are non-zero.

Also, the last bit (bit31) only tells you about 7 bits of the last byte (and only if the first 3 bytes are non-zero) -- if it is the only bit set then the last byte is 0 or 128 (and the rest are non-zero).